# Is there a runtime difference in getting a length of primitive (string, number) type array vs. custom object type array?

Tags: arrays, time-complexity, runtime

In javascript, does getting a length of a number type array vs. custom object type array take the same time?
First array has elements of type number. Second has custom type something like this but not limited to:

```
ISomeType: {
 e1: string,
 e2: ISomeOtherType,
 ..
 e16: number
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: TypeScript is only around at compile time. It then produces JavaScript and *that* is what is running.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a JavaScript question than a TypeScript question, since it's about runtime behavior.

No, there's no difference in the speed of reading the `length` property. It's just a property of the array object (an "own" property, not inherited), exactly the same in both cases.

---

Slightly tangential, but: *Setting* the `length` of an array could theoretically have surprising time characteristics. Array objects are "exotic" objects (ones that don't behave like normal objects) and one of the ways they're exotic is that although `length` [is defined as a data property](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-array-instances-length) (not an accessor property with getter and setter methods), setting it has a side effect: If you set it so that some elements in the array will no longer be in the array, the properties for those elements are removed. Here's an example:

```js
const a = ["a", "b", "c"];
console.log(a.length); // 3
console.log(a[2]);     // c
a.length = 1;          // Removes the "b" and "c" elements
console.log(a.length); // 1
console.log(a[2]);     // undefined
```

In theory, then, if you have a really, really big array (say, millions of elements) and you set `length` such that you're removing a **lot** of elements from the array, you'd see a larger delay than if you did that with a small array where you were removing only a few elements. But you'd have to have a truly massive array, and JavaScript engines could optimize the process (for instance, not really removing the properties, but instead checking later on retrieval whether they should still exist).